# Image is not being accessed through port 8000(under development)

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-staticfiles

My image path is working but Idk why it's not able to display it, any help is appreciated

models.py

```
class movies(models.Model):
    Image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = 'media'
```

home.html

```
{% for m in movies %}
    <img src="{{ m.Image.url }}" width="200px", height="300px">
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was with the Media root, my path was fine but Django wasn't able to get it somehow, so I ran this code to automate Django to find media root by itself

```
ENV_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ENV_PATH, 'media/')
```

and made a debug condition in the urls.py to run the request if viewed under development or localhost

```
if settings.DEBUG is True:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1):

class movies(models.Model):
    Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)

Comment: set your media root with base directory

Comment: already did it and that doesn't answer my question either, as I said my path is working fine, I tested with inspect element but somehow its not displaying it